# Adding users to Gmail via API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps

I have a web form that our HR department uses to add new employees. It adds them to the database, inserts them into Active Directory, and a few other things. We would like it to also create their Gmail account and subscribe them to groups (our current users are already in Gmail under our domain).

Everything I find requires OAuth2 for this, yet it seemingly requires a prompt.  "Google displays a consent screen to the user".

Is there a way to do what I want behind the scenes without any sort of prompt?

Comment: At least the first time you'll be required to display the consent to the user. Then, if you use the refresh_token, you can always exchange the token without require user interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some testing.

Comment: You could create a tool that's authorized via a super admin account in the background and then grant access to that tool via w/e UI you're planning to use. An example of this would be using Apps Script to authorize the Directory API with a SA account and then giving access to a form that triggers the Script. This also has the benefit of not having to grant users in the HR department any admin access for their accounts as the API isn't being accessed with theirs.